# Error:cannot find symbol class onClickListner

Tags: class

The `View.onClickListner` found error...help me solve it..
[image]

**Error**
[image]

Comment: `o` in `onClickListener` should be `O` i.e, capital O.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the 
     View.onClickListener
for 
     View.OnClickListener

that will work, use autocompletion in the IDE.

Thank you